# How to fetch an array of values as JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Assuming I have a table `FamousPeople` with a column `Name`, with 3 names:

1. `John`
2. `Mary`
3. `Freddie Mercury`

Doing this:

```
SELECT
    'Some Random Value' AS someColumnName,
    (SELECT name FROM FamousPeople
     FOR JSON PATH) AS famousPeopleName
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

I get this result:

```
{
  "someColumnName": "Some Random Value",
  "famousPeopleName":
  [
    {"name":"John"},
    {"name":"Mary"},
    {"name":"Freddie Mercury"}
  ]
}
```

I was wondering if there is any way to get the `famousPeopleName` result column as an array of strings:

```
{
  "someColumnName": "Some Random Value",
  "famousPeopleName":
  [
    "John",
    "Mary",
    "Freddie Mercury"
  ]
}
```

Of course, using only T-SQL features, no mad scientist string manipulation in T-SQL (otherwise known as kick in the Netherlands)

Comment: those mad scientist string manipulation in T-SQL are  also T-SQL features

Answer (score 0):

You can use build the array with `JSON_QUERY` and `FOR XML`, then extract the entire json fragment:

```
declare @FamousPeople table([name] varchar(50))

insert into @FamousPeople values
('John'),('Mary'),('Freddie Mercury')

SELECT 'Some Random Value' AS someColumnName,
JSON_QUERY(
    '[' + STUFF(( SELECT ',' + '"' + [name] + '"' 
    FROM @FamousPeople 
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']' ) famousPeopleName  
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```js
{
    "someColumnName": "Some Random Value",
    "famousPeopleName": 
    [
        "John",
        "Mary",
        "Freddie Mercury"
    ]
}
```